# Trying to connect my RaspberryPi4 to a Bluetooth modem and have it trusted and paired, but get error can't connect RFCOMM socket

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, modem

I have a RaspberryPi 4 and am trying to connect it to a Bluetooth modem.

I have paired and trusted the modem, but when I try to connect to the modem I get the message that the connection failed (from Blueman) and that it "Can't connect RFCOMM socket".

Using bluetoothctl, I obtain the following:-

```
Name: Bluetooth Modem - Serial No. xxxxx
Alias: Bluetooth Modem - Serial No. xxxxx
Class: 0x00420210
Icon: modem
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: yes
UUID: Serial Port               
UUID: Dialup Networking         
UUID: Fax
```

What am I doing wrong, so that I can connect (I would like to connect the modem ultimately using efax)?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you run `bluetoothctl` as root?

Comment: Many thanks for your help  - I was about to try the sudo bluetoothctl - as I couldn't even get it to work on Ubuntu 20.04 - and had tried turning the modem off and on again, and turned BT off and on again, and now it all works - no idea why! My sincere thanks again